# Fix Runtime 48 error moving office products

Tags: excel, vb6

We've recently moved PCs over to windows 10 and Office 365 this seems to hav stopped some coding working on an excisting VB6 project we have give the error

Run-time error '48'

Error in loading DLL

Heres the coding where it errors -

```
Set oXLApp = New Excel.Application

oXLApp.Visible = True

Set oXLBook = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)

Set oXLBook = oXLApp.Workbooks.Add(ExcelFileName)

Set oXLSheet = oXLBook.Worksheets(1)
```

Comment: Have you seen this? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/

Comment: Hi, That doesnt really help much?

Comment: Did you move to Office x64?

Comment: Yeah we did and windows 10 64

Comment: Then it's not clear why your Excel reference points to the x86 version.

Comment: This programme was built on a windows 7 pc 32 bit running an older version office if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your references and replace the one that point to old excel dll to the new one

Comment: Sorry, do you know what the new references would be and where i find the old ones to check?

Comment: Load your sources into vb6 ide and go to project/references to uncheck missing ones. Then check those corresponding to the version you need, i think it's Microsoft Excel 16.0

Comment: Hi @EddiGordo seems that the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Libary is already ticked, any other ideas?

Comment: That is curious. No one of your references is tagged "Missing" in the list ?